# Sending user_id and retrieving User records

Tags: php, android, mysql, android-recyclerview

Hi Im new in android and i was wondering how can I send the user_id to my php file and then make it retrieve information about the user (recycler view) for example I want to retrieve the borrowed books(BookName, dateBorrowed, Pages, etc ) from table "BorrowedBooks" . Here is my MainActivity
The user_id is a foreign key of the table "BorrowedBooks".

```
package com.androidcss.jsonexample;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

// CONNECTION_TIMEOUT and READ_TIMEOUT are in milliseconds
public static final int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 10000;
public static final int READ_TIMEOUT = 15000;
private RecyclerView mRVFishPrice;
private AdapterNotif mAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_notifmainactivity);
    //Make call to AsyncTask
    new AsyncLogin().execute();
}

private class AsyncLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    ProgressDialog pdLoading = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
    HttpURLConnection conn;
    URL url = null;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        //this method will be running on UI thread
        pdLoading.setMessage("\tLoading...");
        pdLoading.setCancelable(false);
        pdLoading.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {

            // Enter URL address where your json file resides
            // Even you can make call to php file which returns json data
            url = new URL("http://192.168.1.7/notif.php");

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return e.toString();
        }
        try {

            // Setup HttpURLConnection class to send and receive data from php and mysql
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

            // setDoOutput to true as we recieve data from json file
            conn.setDoOutput(true);

        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
            return e1.toString();
        }

        try {

            int response_code = conn.getResponseCode();

            // Check if successful connection made
            if (response_code == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                // Read data sent from server
                InputStream input = conn.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
                StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                String line;

                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    result.append(line);
                }

                // Pass data to onPostExecute method
                return (result.toString());

            } else {

                return ("unsuccessful");
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return e.toString();
        } finally {
            conn.disconnect();
        }


    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        //this method will be running on UI thread

        pdLoading.dismiss();
        List<DataNotif> data=new ArrayList<>();

        pdLoading.dismiss();
        try {

            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);

            // Extract data from json and store into ArrayList as class objects
            for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                DataNotif fishData = new DataNotif();

                fishData.NotifTitle= json_data.getString("notif_Title");
                fishData.NotifMessage= json_data.getString("notif_Message");
//                    fishData.sizeName= json_data.getString("size_name");
                fishData.Date= json_data.getString("notif_date");
                data.add(fishData);
            }

            // Setup and Handover data to recyclerview
            mRVFishPrice = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.fishPriceList);
            mAdapter = new AdapterNotif(MainActivity.this, data);
            mRVFishPrice.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            mRVFishPrice.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this));

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

}
}
```

and here is my php code

```
<?php
//open connection to mysql db
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","jmilibrary") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($connection));

//fetch table rows from mysql db
$sql = "select * from notification";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die("Error in Selecting " . mysqli_error($connection));

//create an array
$emparray = array();
while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $emparray[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($emparray);

//close the db connection
mysqli_close($connection);
?>
```

Comment: Is your code working? If not - what is the problem? What kind of help do you expect?

Comment: just a tip, for networking you usually want to use google library called Volley, it is much fast + it handles most of the thing for you anyway (for example you dont have to write async task yourself)

Comment: @Egor   Its working fine sir I just dont know how to send the users, user_id and making my php receive the user_id then get the data from my database

Comment: @MarkoNiciforovic I dont know Volley that much and how to implement it in a recycleview but none the less ill test your tip sir thanks ^^

Answer (score 0):

On PHP side write same script as above and replace `$sql` with the new command like

```
$sql = "select book_information from table where id = " . $_GET["id"];
```

On the client side make same request as above just add `id` to the `URL` like

```
url = new URL("http://192.168.1.7/notif.php?id="+UserID);
```

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: its correct... but the actual q.s is ' I want to retrieve the borrowed books(BookName, dateBorrowed, Pages, etc ) from table "BorrowedBooks" ', i should be deserve down voted if I didn't provide answer to it..

Comment: I dont know much about mysql injection my php may not require security for the reason that there wont be any inputbox in the application on the event of passing the user_id but ill check he's code then add some security afterwards thanks. @zsee433 ill chech your code tomorrow if it would work for me thanks, need some rest ^^

Comment: @earlcabanig Use prepared statements. It saves a ton of time and hassle, you'll never have to track down some dumb escaping mistake you've made. It doesn't matter where the data is coming from, it doesn't matter if you *think* it'll be safe. Do it right the first time and don't worry about it ever again. Littering your code with time-bombs like this is completely crazy and is liable to blow up in a huge way when you least expect it or can ill afford it.

Comment: @zsee433 Putting `$_GET` values directly in the query is **never** the correct answer to anything.

Comment: @tadman Thanks sir ill keep it in mind ^^. Can you share your way of doing this process securely?

Comment: @zsee433 I forgot to mention that the user_id is not a primary key but a foreign key I updated my post. how can I send the user_id then retrieve the info now sir?

Comment: @zsee433 I think this solve my problem If nobody will post by tomorrow or I wont have any problems with your answer Ill mark you as correct thanks ^^

Comment: to make it simple, just update your query on server script like `select book_infos from table A inner join table_user on A.user_id = table_user.id  where table_user.id = id`

Comment: @zsee433 Prepared statements with placeholder values, as in the links I've put in the comments. It's not hard. It is safe.

Answer (score -1):

Use [Okhttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/) or volley android.

On Android with Okhtttp:

```
    buildernew.addFormDataPart("user_id","YOUR USER ID");

    MultipartBody requestBody = buildernew.build();
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build();
    okhttp3.Request request = new okhttp3.Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .post(requestBody)
            .build()
            ;

    Call call = client.newCall(request);
    call.enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
            Log.e("respons is error", "Registration error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, okhttp3.Response response) throws IOException {
            try {
                String jsonData = response.body().string();
                JSONObject Jobject = new JSONObject(jsonData);
                JSONArray jr = Jobject.getJSONArray("notification");
                for (int i = 0; i < jr.length(); i++) {
                    DataNotif fishData = new DataNotif();
                    JSONObject object = jr.getJSONObject(i);
                    fishData.NotifTitle(object.getString("notif_Title"));
                    fishData.NotifMessage(object.getString("notif_Message"));
                    fishData.Date(object.getString("notif_date"));
                    data.add(personal);
                }
                response.body().close();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("respons is not Ok", "Exception caught: ", e);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

On PHP:

```
function connectToDatabase(){
$connection=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "jmilibrary");
  mysqli_set_charset($connection, 'utf8');
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
return $connection;
}

$connection = connectToDatabase();
$user_id = $_REQUEST['user_id'];
$result = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM book_information WHERE id=$user_id");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  $record['id'] = $row['id'];
  $record['notif_Title'] = $row['notif_Title'];
  $record['notif_Message'] = $row['notif_Message'];     
$record['notif_date'] = $row['notif_date'];
   $notification['notification'][] = $record;
}
echo json_encode($notification);
mysqli_close($connection);
```

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Learning is fine, but learn to do it the correct way and don't be sloppy about it. Mistakes like this can have huge consequences.

Comment: @Farhad do you know what I should add with just my code as I dont know volley and okhttp im new to this as well as java. though I want to learn but it will take time and currently im lacking of it.